# What are these android elements?

Tags: android

This is a screenshot of the Tinder app.
There is a button for "upgrading", some sort of vertical separator, followed by a button for "settings"

Does any veteran android developer know how these 3 elements are commonly implemented?

(The icon/text button & separator) Any advice or reference articles to point me in the right direction would be most appreciated

[image]

Comment: This could be implemented by two `ImageView`, one having a right border.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
Wouldn't having an ImageView be an extremely bad idea for localization?

Comment: OK then use a `TextView` next to an `ImageView`.  Have you searched SO for this?

Comment: For the buttons you can use a Button with a `drawableLeft`.

Comment: For vertical line you can use View in xml . Set the height of view to match_parent and width to 2dp .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line can be generated with **View** And **DrawableLeft** for TextView to show icons on left

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view"
android:drawablePadding="5dp"
android:scaleX="0.7"
android:scaleY="0.7"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_add"
android:text="GET TINDER PLUS"
android:textColor="#F33379" />

<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="35dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:drawablePadding="7dp"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
    android:textColor="#F33379" />
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful!